# Interface method returns ArrayList containing different objects

Tags: java, oop, interface, arraylist, polymorphism

I have an interface to initialize data that will generate list containing different object types:

```
public interface DataInitializer {
    public void initializeData();
    public ArrayList<> getData();
}
```

When I implement this abstract the getData() method of the implementing class will need to return ArrayLists containing different types of objects for example:

```
public ArrayList<Faculty> getData()
public ArrayList<Student> getData()
```

How to I account for this needed flexibility in the interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

```
public interface DataInitializer {
    public void initializeData();
    public <T> ArrayList<T> getData();
}
```

Or on interface level

```
public interface DataInitializer<T> {
    public void initializeData();
    public ArrayList<T> getData();
}
```

Implementation example:

```
class StudentInitializer implements DataInitializer<Student> {
 public ArrayList<Student> getData() {

 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to why my question was down voted?

Comment: @BrianVanover: I don't know the reasoning behind whoever did it. Maybe they thought you should've found out yourself that you need generics, but it's really just guessing here.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question ban :/

Comment: @BrianVanover: if you would like assistance with this then you should go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. We'll look through your history then and moderators can shine more light on your particular situation.